# How does SFMC Journey Builder handle Lead to Contact conversions that happen in Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, lead-conversion

My team wants to trigger a nurture journey in SFMC Journey Builder when SFDC Leads/Contacts fill out a web form. If the web visitor is net new to our company it will get created as a SFDC Lead in SFDC CRM and will enter the SFMC journey as a SFDC Lead. My colleagues created some decision splits that contain SFDC CRM **Contact** object fields after different wait steps to check specific SFDC Contact fields *if* the original SFDC Lead got converted while the Lead was moving along the journey.

In other words, can we reference Contact attributes after a Lead got converted while still going through a journey?

How does Journey Builder manage IDs upon Lead to Contact conversions? For instance, if a SFDC Lead gets converted while being in a journey, does Journey Builder automatically knows what is the SFDC Contact Id?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not implemented a custom lead conversion process in SF that fails to update all of the Lead object's system fields, you should just run your decision split on the "IsConverted" field on the Lead object.

That being said, there should be a data relationship from Lead to Contact in your schema that will be visible in Contact Builder. That object defaults to matching where Lead:ConvertedContactId = Contact:Id, so you could match on Contact by using a decision split where that relationship is valid (unconverted Leads would have a NULL value for this property).

There are a lot of ways to approach this that will differ greatly depending on your SF configuration. From the sound of your implementation, I'd guess that the first option would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but when someone enters a journey as a SFDC Lead and a conversion to the Contact object happens when the person is in the journey, does Journey Builder considers this person as a SFDC Contact moving forward? For example, if that person reaches a decision split made of SFDC Contact fields only, will that decision split work? We have the mapping Lead:ConvertedContactId = Contact:Id

Comment: You'll have to do an attribute comparison to get that information in your decision split. Your journey will not recognize them as a contact moving forward as the ID that you are associating to the journey entrant would be the LeadID and cannot be modified mid-journey. You need to exit these records from your Lead journey and create a Contact journey that would pick them up as soon as they become a contact.

Comment: Additionally to the same ques., what happens to Lead Tracking info? Does it disappears once its converted to contact?